# Contexe Error Exception in FOSUserbundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I just read the documentation of `FOSUserBundle` and when I was just copying codes from the ducumentation. And when I went to some page, it gave me an error page like this:

```
ContextErrorException: Runtime Notice: Declaration of Neejob\CompanyBundle\Controller\RegistrationController::registerAction() should be compatible with FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController::registerAction(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request) in D:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\src\Neejob\CompanyBundle\Controller\RegistrationController.php line 9
```

however, when i refresh the page, it turned out to work fine. But As I clear the cache, the same problem occurs. How should I handle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that you have to check declaration of registerAction method and change it exactly like in parent class.

Replace:

```
public function registerAction()
```

With:

```
public function registerAction(Request $request)
```

And don't forget to add `use` statement

Comment: Oh, mgd! I forgot to add use statement. Thank you Vadim!

Comment: Well, but as i refresh the page, it works out fine, could you please tell me why?

Comment: I think this is due to symfony cache system. On first request you get the error because the file is not cached, on second request file cached in one BIG file and use statement of `Request` class is there.